# Go escape comma in JSON

Tags: json, go

http://play.golang.org/p/lF2ZgAyxei

How do I escape comma in JSON tag in Go?

```
type AA struct {
  MyStr string `json:"sub,ject"`
}

func main() {
  jsonStr := `
  {
    "sub,ject":         "I"
  }
  `
  stt := new(AA)
  json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonStr), stt)
  fmt.Println(stt)

  t, _ := strconv.Unquote(jsonStr)
  fmt.Println(t)
}
```

This does not grab the key and only returns empty results.

How do I escape the comma?

Answer (score 7):

The code used by the JSON encoding package to parse field tags is in [tags.go](http://golang.org/src/pkg/encoding/json/tags.go). This code splits the field name from the options at the first comma. It not possible to escape the comma.

Comment: Note that you can still unmarshal to a string map: http://play.golang.org/p/93AJCj4tFP